# Axum: pass parameters to handlers

Tags: rust, rust-axum, jwt-simple

new to rust here. I am trying to build a simple server that provides and decodes JWT tokens and I am missing a big part. Here is the code:

```
pub struct Server {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: String,
    pub public_key: String,
    pub private_key: String
}

impl Server {
    pub async fn start(&self) {
      let routes = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(check))
        .route("/auth", post(auth));
      let mut hostport = String::from(&self.host);
      hostport.push_str(":");
      hostport.push_str(&self.port);
      println!("{}", hostport);
      let addr : SocketAddr = hostport.parse().expect("invalid host:port pair");
      axum::Server::bind(
          &addr
      ).serve(routes.into_make_service()).await.unwrap();
    }
}

async fn auth(Json(payload): Json<LoginInput>) -> impl IntoResponse {
  let claims = Claims::create(Duration::from_hours(1));
  RS384PublicKey::from_pem("id_like_to_put_Server::public_key_here").sign(claims)?;
  let lo = LoginOutput{
    token: payload.username
  };
  (StatusCode::OK, Json(lo))
}
```

As you can see `Server` holds routing logic and applies configuration. Among configuration there is a public key I'd like to use in order to sign the JWT token (I am using `jwt_simple` to achieve that). Since public key is a `Server`'s attribute, I want to pass that value to the `auth` handler but I can't figure out how to do that. How can I pass a parameter to an `Axum` handler and sign the token is generated inside?

Comment: This use case fits well with State in Axum: https://docs.rs/axum/0.6.0-rc.2/axum/index.html#sharing-state-with-handlers

Comment: @bits hello! State is cool but, now you show me (thankyou!), I'd rather prefer to use Extensions.. If only I can find an example... Any hints about this? TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although here are the examples using both Extension and State, State is preferred as from the docs of Axum:

> You should prefer using State if possible since it’s more type safe. The downside is that its less dynamic than request extensions.

In Cargo.toml:

```rust
[dependencies]
axum = "0.6.0-rc.2"
serde = { version = "1.0.147", features = ["derive"] }
tokio = { version = "1.21.2", features = ["macros", "rt-multi-thread"] }
```

**Using State:**

```
use std::net::SocketAddr;

use axum::{
    extract::State,
    response::IntoResponse,
    routing::{get, post},
    Json, Router,
};
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ServerConfig {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: String,
    pub public_key: String,
    pub private_key: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct LoginInput {
    username: String,
    password: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let server_config = ServerConfig {
        host: "0.0.0.0".into(),
        port: "8080".into(),
        public_key: "public_key".into(),
        private_key: "private_key".into(),
    };

    let addr: SocketAddr = format!("{}:{}", server_config.host, server_config.port)
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    let routes = Router::with_state(server_config) // state will be available to all the routes
        .route("/", get(check))
        .route("/auth", post(auth));

    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(routes.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn check() -> &'static str {
    "check"
}

async fn auth(
    State(server_config): State<ServerConfig>, // extract state in this handler
    // `Json` supports any type that implements `serde::Deserialize`
    Json(payload): Json<LoginInput>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // use server_config and payload to run the `auth` logic
    println!("host: {}", server_config.host);

    "jwt"
}
```

**Using Extension**

```rust
use std::net::SocketAddr;

use axum::{
    response::IntoResponse,
    routing::{get, post},
    Extension, Json, Router,
};
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Clone)]
pub struct ServerConfig {
    pub host: String,
    pub port: String,
    pub public_key: String,
    pub private_key: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct LoginInput {
    username: String,
    password: String,
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let server_config = ServerConfig {
        host: "0.0.0.0".into(),
        port: "8080".into(),
        public_key: "public_key".into(),
        private_key: "private_key".into(),
    };

    let addr: SocketAddr = format!("{}:{}", server_config.host, server_config.port)
        .parse()
        .unwrap();

    let routes = Router::new()
        .route("/", get(check))
        .route("/auth", post(auth))
        .layer(Extension(server_config));

    axum::Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(routes.into_make_service())
        .await
        .unwrap();
}

async fn check() -> &'static str {
    "check"
}

async fn auth(
    Extension(server_config): Extension<ServerConfig>,
    // `Json` supports any type that implements `serde::Deserialize`
    Json(payload): Json<LoginInput>,
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    // use server_config and payload to run the `auth` logic
    println!("host: {}", server_config.host);

    "jwt"
}
```